# import vue.js get error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, vue.js

I'm learning to use vue.js when I try to use multiple vue libraries, I get an error when I import some library like vue-router , does anyone know ? 
thank you before

this is my code :

```
import Vue from 'vue' ;
import VueRouter from 'vue-router' ;

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#App',
    data: {
      message: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
  })

export default new Router({
    routes: [
        {
            path: 'http://localhost/HAD_point_of_sale/',
            redirect: {
                name: "login"
            }
        },
        {
            path: 'http://localhost/HAD_point_of_sale/karyawan',
            redirect: {
                name: "karyawan"
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

than i got an error :
[image: error vue]

[image]

Comment: This has to be something pretty fundamental. Is it a vue-cli project or are you importing the CDN?

Comment: It seems like you did not install `vue` from any package manager at all.

Comment: @Andrew1325 i'm using CDN

Comment: are you using laravel?  so you should try to run laravel-mix  app.js (be sure to have installed npm and node js)

Comment: it was solve thank you for the explanation

Comment: I'm also facing same issue. I've installed it locally from npm.

Comment: Hey Herdy, Can you please tell me how did you solve this?

Comment: @Babbar thak you its resolved

Comment: Please include how you resolved this as an answer to this question.